# Could not complete schema update Envers + Firebird

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

- hibernate-core 4.3.7
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
- hibernate-envers 4.3.11
- Firebird 2.5.5

I'm trying use Envers but i have a trouble: 
Could not complete schema update: org.hibernate.MappingException: org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect does not support pooled sequences

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GEN_BOOKS", sequenceName = "GEN_BOOKS", allocationSize = 1)
@Audited
public class BOOK implements Serializable , Comparable<BOOK> {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_BOOKS")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can generate your tables if you comment on those lines:

```
//@SequenceGenerator(name = "GEN_BOOKS", sequenceName = "GEN_BOOKS", allocationSize = 1)
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_BOOKS")
```

Is necessary in Persistence:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Start server and tables will be created.

Then now is necessary create manually Trigguer and Generator

```
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_BOOKS;
SET GENERATOR GEN_BOOKS TO 1;

CREATE TRIGGER TR_BOOKS_ID FOR BOOKS
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_BOOKS , 1);
   END ;

COMMIT WORK;
```

Delete Persistence:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Delete Coments in

```
//@SequenceGenerator(name = "GEN_BOOKS", sequenceName = "GEN_BOOKS", allocationSize = 1)
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_BOOKS")
```

Instead you can manually create tables

Annotation `@AuditedTable ( value = "BOOKS_LOG")`

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS_AUD(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,         
  REV     INTEGER NOT NULL,    <-- IMPORTANT
  REVTYPE SMALLINT,            <-- IMPORTANT
  TITLE VARCHAR(45)

);
```

GENERATOR and TRIGGER

```
   CREATE REVINFO (     
        ID integer not null, 
        REV integer not null, 
        REVTYPE smallint, 
        TITLE varchar(45) 
    );

    ALTER TABLE REVINFO ADD
    PRIMARY KEY (ID ,REV);
```

GENERATOR and TRIGGER

Answer (score 0):

It seems like currently Hibernate doesn't suppose that

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8979